# Texture not being applied on .OBJ file

Tags: texturing

[image: Image for reference]Started learning Blender less than a week ago and I'm having some trouble with textures.

I want to apply a texture to this imported .OBJ file by doing the usual Unwrap->Material Properties->Image Texture procedure, yet it seems that the texture isn't being properly applied. This isn't the case with other objects like the plane it is on as shown by the image. I assumed my object was just too large but when I try to zoom in as much as possible I still can't see an ounce of texture. Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whenever you're asking questions about materials you should post screenshots of the material node graph, usually the issue with materials will stem from something in that view mode.

Answer (score 0):

The unwrap worked for the plane because it's just a simple 2D plane, so there is no complexity to unwrap.

For your more complex object, if you want correct UV's, you will need to manually create edge seams, and then unwrap the mesh.

You can also try Smart UV Project, and see if it works for you.